websocket.io not updates correctly on new vote push
I try to update the websocket.io when a new vote is cast with the new vote only to be displayed live on the website. But for some reason it does not fetch the new vote and only shows the first vote that have been cast in the session. I have tried multiplied solutions i came to this but this do the same for some reason I don't know how to fix it.
The votes comes from the voteCollection the we join the tokens collection to fetch the details about the project. That seems to work correctly the only error is that the new vote do not get pushed.
Here is the backend:
import {
    createServer
} from 'http';
import {
    Server as SocketIOServer
} from 'socket.io';
import clientPromise from '../../lib/mongo-db';


export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        try {
            // Connect to the MongoDB client
            const client = await clientPromise;
            const db = client.db(process.env.DB_NAME);


            // Access the specific collections needed
            const projectCollection = db.collection('tokens');
            const votesCollection = db.collection('votes');

            // Get the latest vote from the votes collection
            const latestVote = await votesCollection.findOne({}, {
                sort: {
                    _id: -1
                }
            });

            if (!latestVote) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    error: 'No votes found'
                });
            }

            // Aggregate to join votes with project details
            const pipeline = [{
                    $match: {
                        _id: latestVote._id
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'tokens',
                        localField: 'projectId',
                        foreignField: '_id',
                        as: 'projectDetails'
                    }
                },
                {
                    $unwind: '$projectDetails'
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 1,
                        vote: 1,
                        'projectDetails.name': 1,
                        'projectDetails.description': 1
                        // Add other fields you want to include from projectDetails
                    }
                }
            ];

            const aggregatedResult = await votesCollection.aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
            const joinedResult = aggregatedResult[0]; // Since there should be only one result

            // Create HTTP server
            const httpServer = createServer((req, res) => {
                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
                });
                res.end('WebSocket server for socket.io');
            });

            // Create socket.io server instance
            const io = new SocketIOServer(httpServer);

            // WebSocket (socket.io) connection handling
            io.on('connection', (socket) => {
                console.log('WebSocket connected');

                // Send the initial joined result to the client
                socket.emit('latestVote', joinedResult);

                // Listen for changes in the votes collection
                const changeStream = votesCollection.watch();
                changeStream.on('change', async () => {
                    const updatedVote = await votesCollection.aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
                    if (updatedVote.length > 0) {
                        socket.emit('latestVote', updatedVote[0]);
                    }
                });

                // Handle disconnect
                socket.on('disconnect', () => {
                    console.log('WebSocket disconnected');
                    changeStream.close();
                });
            });

            // Start HTTP server
            httpServer.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
                console.log(`Socket.IO server running on port ${process.env.PORT || 3000}`);
            });

            // Respond with success
            res.status(200).end();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: 'Internal Server Error'
            });
        }
    } else {
        res.setHeader('Allow', ['GET']);
        return res.status(405).json({
            error: `Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`
        });
    }
}

Here is how I fetch the data to my frontend I think that's correct:
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDataAndSetupSocket = async () => {
      try {
        await fetch('/api/get-latest-vote');

        const socket = io();

        socket.on('connect', () => {
          console.log('connect');
          socket.emit('hello');
        });

        socket.on('latestVote', (data) => {
          console.log('lates vote data', data);
        });

        socket.on('a user connected', () => {
          console.log('a user connected');
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
          console.log('disconnect');
        });

        return () => {
          socket.disconnect();
        };
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchDataAndSetupSocket();
  }); 

This is all the code.
